# Missing Template Error Rails 3 though all views are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get Missing Template Error certain times for a valid html page request to my rails 3.0 application.

I have all the view (.html.erb) files in place. How come, only some times, this error happens. HTTP_ACCEPT_FORMAT for the requests is "text/*" .. does this have anything to do with the error ?

Please help guys..

Here is the render line where the error occurs

```
    render "company_page", :layout => "application"
```

Also, when I saw the USER AGENT, it shows this in hoptoad,

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; oBot/2.3.1; +http://www-935.ibm.com/services/us/index.wss/detail/iss/a1029077?cntxt=a1027244)"
```

It seems to be a bot. Why is this oBot not getting my html when I render html page only for that url

Comment: Can you give us a stacktrace?

Comment: stacktrace and any respond_to calls in your controller would be helpful